# Multiple radio buttons inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i was trying to build a simple class attendance system in this program first i am fetching name value from table called class1 then i am trying to insert that name and attendance in table name class1attendance. But when i trying to submit it i am getting same value for all students whatever i select first radio button for example i have many students first student is Richard when i choose present radio button for Richard i am getting present stored in my database for rest of students. Here is my code

```
<?php 

include('header.php');
include('mysqli_connect.php');
echo "<br> <br>";

$q = "SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Name FROM class1";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

echo '<div class = "container">';

echo '

<table>

<tr class = " w3-padding w3-green w3-xlarge "> <td> Student Name </td>

<td> Absent/Present </td>

 </tr>';

 $attendance ; 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
     $attendance ; 
    if($_POST['attendance'] == 'present')
    {
        $attendance = 'present';
    }
    else
    {
        $attendance = 'absent';
    }

}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
    $name =  $row['Name'];
    $q1 = "INSERT INTO class1attendance(s_id, first_name, attendance) VALUES (0, '$name', '$attendance')";

    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);
    echo '<tr> 
    <td>' . $name . '</td> <td>
    <form method = "post" action = "">
    Present <input type = "radio" name = "attendance" value = "present" class = "w3-radio">
    Absent <input type = "radio" name = "attendance" value = "absent" class = "w3-radio">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit Attendence" class = "w3-btn w3-green w3-round">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>';;


}


echo '</div>
</table>';


?>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? We obviously can't test the code on our own since we do not have access to the database. So giving us a sample data object to us would be helpful.

Comment: I have one table name as class1 where i am storing information about students like student_id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, parents_name, admission_date, admission_fee, first_installment, second_installment. From this table i am retrieving first_name and last_name and storing it in table named as class1attendance where i m storing student's first_name, last_name and attendance, roll number. Where attendance will be just present and absent. i hope it clarifies a bit to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need unique `names` for all your radio button groups.

Each student gets a group: "absent" & "present".

So you would need to do something like

```
name=" $first_name + $last_name +'attendance'"
```

Idk php but that's the idea.  Otherwise you are only producing one radio group and therefore getting one value.

____EDIT____

Ultimately, you want your HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <!-- radio group 1 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        John Doe
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="JohnDoe0">
          Absent
          <input id="JohnDoe0" type="radio" name="JohnDoe_attendance" value="absent"/>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="JohnDoe1">
          Present
          <input id="JohnDoe1" type="radio" name="JohnDoe_attendance" value="present"/>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--/ end radoi group 1 -->

    <!-- radio group 2 -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        Jane Doe
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="JaneDoe0">
          Absent
          <input id="JaneDoe0" type="radio" name="JaneDoe_attendance" value="absent"/>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="JaneDoe1">
          Present
          <input id="JaneDoe1" type="radio" name="JaneDoe_attendance" value="present"/>
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--/ end radoi group 2 -->
  </table>
```

So in order to receive your values properly, each name for each radio-group needs to be unique.

So if you have 20 students, you have 20 unique `name` attributes.  Each student gets 2 radio buttons.  Both of those radio buttons get that name.

NOTE: I wouldn't put a form in a table.  I would use CSS to format the form.  However, I would display the results of that form in a table.

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for your reply i tried to replace my name variable with $name+absent and $name+present in radio button input but still it didn't workout for me.

Comment: From what you're showing me, you're creating one too many unique names per student.  Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thanks Tamb for amazing explanation it made my concept clear but didn't helped me to sort out this problem. Thanks again